# GWT : How to call SERVLET FROM GWT_SERVLET and How to return value from target servlet to source servlet?

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, gwt-rpc

I have 2 servlets.

One In GWT module i.e **BasicServiceImpl** extends RemoteServiceServlet implements BasicMassUpdateService

and other servlet **TargetServlet** extends HttpServlet in TargetServlet in diff module/package com.comp.server.servlets

I am using GWT-RPC in my gwt module. I want to write one method getRecordList() in BasicServiceImpl which returns list of record on client side.(right now I am sending dummy data in record list)

In other servlet i.e TargetServlet RecordList formed from database value.

Use case:
When we call getRecordList() method using rpc then I want to call SERVLET : TargetServlet to get recordlist, TargetServlet will return recordlist to getRecordList of Gwt_servlet and finally getRecordList() returns recordlist on client side

1: How to call other servlet(TargetServlet) from GWT_SERVLET i.e **BasicServiceImpl**

2: How to send recordlist from TargetServlet to getRecordList() of BasicServiceImpl(GWT SERVLET)

Any help or guidance in this matter would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1,2. Have you tried using URLFetch for this?

BasicServiceImpl URLFetches the TargetServlet and TargetServlet adds it's information to the response. BasicServiceImpl reads that response and returns it to client side gwt.

Comment: I am using GWT not GAE. URLFectch is API of GAE

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is directly way to talk between servlets, but at least you can create doPost method to non-GWT one, and make http query from GWT servlet to non-GWT to get data ... tough this need bit building as you need to serialize data for http post and unserialize for GWT servletside, and then again GWT servlet will serialize data again for client.